# Scaling images in UIWebView iOS

Tags: ios, uiwebview, scale

I am using `UIWebView` to display a snippet of HTML in an iOS app. The HTML does not come from me, it comes from a public RSS feed (from the `description` field).

It looks fine, except the images are sometimes too wide to fit. I know the ideal way is in CSS, but since the HTML isn't mine... What's the easiest fix?

Comment: Have you tried `UIWebView`'s scalesPageToFit property ?

Comment: Get the HTML in a string then search for img Tags, check their sizes, If more than what you need replace those values in string.